# jQuery DataTable JS not working(ASP .NET 3-tier architecture)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I am using a 3-tier architecture in my project, which has the following structure :

1. Web Pages(has reference to BusinessLogic(C# Class)
2. Business Logic(has reference to the DataAccess(C# class) contains all the methods for data access.
3. DataAccess - contains methods for database operations(Insert,Update,Delete,etc)

Now in my website, I am using a **MasterPage-ContentPage** relationship. As I have learned I am loading all my scripts and CSS for the individual pages in my master page.

Here is my bottom section(scripts references) of the Master Page :

```
 <!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.2 JS -->
    <script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- SlimScroll -->
    <script src="../../plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src='../../plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js'></script>

    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="../../dist/js/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="dist/js/toastr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Demo -->
    <script src="../../dist/js/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- DATA TABES SCRIPT -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#example').dataTable();
    </script>
```

Here is the top section(CSS references) of my master page :

```
 <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.4 -->
    <link href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="dist/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins 
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

As I have seen from the official [jQuery DataTable tutorial page](https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html), this is the way I should initialize my DataTable in my script.

Still when I run the CSS works as expected, but the JS doesn't work as I tried to use the functions like **sorting,searching,etc.** - NOTHING WORKS.

This is my content page for reference :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Products : </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptr" runat="server">

            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th >Sr. No</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Company</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>In Stock</th>
                            <th>Min. Qty</th>
                            <th>Date Created</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("ProdName") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("CategoryName") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("CompanyName") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("ProdPrice") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("QuantityInStock")%></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("MinQuantity")%></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("DateCreated")%></td>
                        <td><a href='<%# "ProductDetails.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ProductID") %>'>View</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

and this is my **PageLoad** method. There are no other methods for the Page except PageLoad :

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["user"] != null)
            {
                rptr.DataSource = new ProductLogic().fillProductTable();
                rptr.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?url=ProductDetails.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

---

I do not know what am I doing wrong. The data is being loaded correctly, the CSS is but the JS doesn't work at all. What is wrong that I am doing here ?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @annoyingmouse : I am going to drop this question, as I have changed my code and used a web service to load data instead! that worked! I ll post my solution soon . I used ajax to load data into datatable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is ufcourse some way other than I am mentioning in my answer to use the jQuery DataTable in your ASP.NET web-application. But I found this the easiest way possible.

**Step-1)** Create a **web service** in your website.In the code below I am converting a **`datatable`** returned from my query result into a **`JSON Array`** with one of the utilities I found on the internet. Here is the code for the WebService :

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for ProductDetailsWebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class ProductDetailsWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public void GetProductDetails()
    {
        ProductLogic prodLogic = new ProductLogic();
        DataTable dt = prodLogic.fillProductTable();

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        Dictionary<string, object> row;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        Context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(rows));
    }


}
```

**Step-2)** The **`HTML`** looks something very simple with a basic `<thead>` tag containing several `<tr>`. Note the **`id`** you give here is important as this id will be used in JS to find the table element. Here is the HTML :

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Category</th>
             <th>Company</th>
             <th>Price</th>
             <th>In Stock</th>
             <th>Min. Qty</th>
             <th>Date Created</th>
             <th>More</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
   </table>
```

**Step-3)** The JS :

```
<!-- DATA TABES SCRIPT -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ProductDetailsWebService.asmx/GetProductDetails',
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var dataTableInstance = $('#datatable').dataTable({
                    data: data,
                    'scrollY': 300,
                    columns: [
                        { 'data': 'ProdName' },
                        { 'data': 'CategoryName' },
                        { 'data': 'CompanyName' },
                        {
                            'data': 'ProdPrice',
                            'render' : $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0)
                        },
                        { 'data': 'QuantityInStock' },
                        { 'data': 'MinQuantity' },
                        {
                            'data': 'DateCreated',
                            'render': function (jsonDate) {
                                var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
                                var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                                return date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            'data': 'ProductID',
                            'searchable' : false,
                            'sortable' : false,
                            'render': function (productID) {
                                return '<a href="ProductDetails.aspx?ID='+ productID +'">Full Details...</a>';
                            }

                        }
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

**NOTE:** You need to have only the CSS and the JS for datatable which can be found at the [jQuery Datable Tutorial Page](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html).

Very Important Video tutorial for the same can be found at [Kudvenkat's jQuery Tutorial series on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgD24a9gxXw&index=106&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVDV697uvHpavA3K_eWGQap).